# remove default icon of jquery mobile listview

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am doing a listview with jquery mobile but I can´t change the icon default of the list of jquery mobile, here is my code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-alt-icon">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example 1 - Custom icons

Working example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5nyFg/).

#### HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="alt">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
.ui-icon-alt:after {
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5d/Mac_App_Store_icon.png');
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

### Exameple 2 - Pre-existing icons

working example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YAaun/).

#### MTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="left">
    <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "data-icon" attribute:

```
<!--this will remove icon-->
<li data-icon="false"><a...</li>

<!--this will change icon to the "home" icon-->
<li data-icon="home"><a...</li>
```